# Looking for information about possible ingredients of a fertilizer

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have found it in a local store, "20.20.0 - Kompoze" is written on the pack. In the pack, there are yellowish greenish irregular formed little balls. What is this, do you know ? Please help and excuse my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

well , maybe you should have had googled it or spoke to the retailer about it . i dont know why you have no but its constituents are 20% nitrogen (N) and 20% phosphorus (P2O5). Afterall there must be NP written above 20-20-0 and these both must must be written above the KOMPOZE and this all will be enclosed in a red disc.and below all this will be a trademark of toros.